# Sending a File between two sockets in Java continuously

Tags: java, sockets

My question is similar to a chat room. where there is continuous communication between the client and the server sockets. In my case, I am seeking a way in which when the client sends a file to the socket, the socket is notified that there is a new file and the socket can make some modification to this file and send back to the client. The client has to know that the file has been modified also. Like I said at the first, when one is using some kind of chat window this is easy to just type in some finishing statement and the other socket can read this message to know if the file is changed or NOT. In my case, I don't have any chat window. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> when the client sends a file to the socket, the socket is notified that there is a new file

That's signalled by the arrival of new data.

> and the socket can make some modification to this file and send back to the client.

Right, so send it.

> The client has to know that the file has been modified also.

That's signalled by the arrival of a reply.

Problem solved. Just send files back and forth. You'll need to prepend the filename and length, and ensure that you read exactly that many bytes, but this is mere programming, and here are hundreds of examples of that here.